# return a list from a complex string

Tags: parsing, haskell, operators

I start with haskell.

I was wondering if I can convert a string to a list of different element's type like that : `"1*30%4" -> ['1', '*', '30', '%', '4']` without Parsec

I have already found answers but none really help me...
like `map (:[]) "1*30%4"`with GHCI
or with the help of `intersperse`.

but I do not know how to keep the right formats, I can not, for example, have numbers or float/double in my list because everything is cut one by one : `"1*30%4" -> ['1', '*', '3', '0', '%', '4']` or `"1*30.4%4" -> ['1', '*', '3', '0', '.', '4', '%', '4']`

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Would you like to do it with a parsing library like Parsec or just do it with vanilla Haskell?

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that I do not want to use Parsec

Comment: List in Haskell cannot hold different type of element. like '30' is not a type of Char, so, it must be broken into '3' and '0' in order to store them in list, say ['1', ...'3', '0' ...]. The thing you need may be list of String, say ["1", ... "30", "%"..] right?

Comment: yes it's exactly that, with the 'Words' function my program works well, but I have to separate everything with spaces, it's very annoying ...

Comment: What's wrong with parser libraries, it's the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some users have pointed out, your returning type is `[String]` instead of `[Char]`. You can easily achieve this by the following:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

expresionToList :: String -> [String]
expresionToList = groupBy readAsNumber
  where readAsNumber c d = pred c && pred d
        pred x = isDigit x || x == '.'
```

- `pred` function returns True when its input is a digit or a dot, False otherwise
- `readAsNumber` takes two returns True if both are a digit or a dot
- finally you group your string by `readAsNumber`

Comment: first time I hear about 'pred'.

Comment: thank you for your help, with the expresionToList function my problem is solved.

Comment: @astrocurieux `pred` function is defined in the where clause. It is not built-in function.